# Cannot pickle Scikit learn NearestNeighbor classifier - can't pickle instancemethod objects

Tags: python, pickle

I'm trying to pickle NearestNeighbor model but it says can't pickle instancemethod objects.

The code:

```
import cPickle as pickle
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors

nbrs = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=50, algorithm='ball_tree', metric=self.distanceCIE2000_classifier)
nbrs.fit(allValues)
with open('/home/ubuntu/nbrs.p','wb') as f:
       pickle.dump(nbrs, f)
```

The full traceback:

```
  File "/home/ubuntu/colorSetter.py", line 82, in createClassifier
    pickle.dump(nbrs, f)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/copy_reg.py", line 70, in _reduce_ex
    raise TypeError, "can't pickle %s objects" % base.__name__
  TypeError: can't pickle instancemethod objects
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere within the `NearestNeighbors` instance is an attribute that refers to the instance method that you passed to it in the `metric` argument. Pickle won't pickle instance methods, hence the error.

One way around it is to move method `distanceCIE2000_classifier()` out of your class to a regular standalone function, if that is possible.